# TLS v1.0 best cipher for OpenVPN setup

Tags: vpn, cipher-selection

I'm trying to setup OpenVPN with as much security as I can. I'm in the process of selecting a cipher for OpenVPN. Which is the safest one, `tls-cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA` or `tls-cipher AES256-SHA`?

I've already configured it with these settings:

- HMAC: SHA512 for auth option
- DH: 2048 bit
- cipher: AES-256-CFB

And password is requested during connection.

My OpenVPN version is 2.2.1. Is my setup OK? I took a look at [this post](https://forums.openvpn.net/topic11913.html) as reference, but I'm not sure, if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the ciphers, use `DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA`.

If you use `openssl ciphers -v` you can get more information about each cipher:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA 
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
$ openssl ciphers -v AES256-SHA
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
```

From this you can see that both ciphers can be used in `SSLv3`, both use RSA for authentication (`Au=RSA`), both use 256-bit AES for encryption (`Enc=AES(256)`), and both use SHA-1 for the message authentication code (`Mac=SHA1`).

So the only difference between these two ciphers is the key exchange. `AES256-SHA` uses RSA for the key exchange (`Kx=RSA`). `DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA` uses ephemeral Diffie–Hellman (`Kx=DH` is Diffie-Hellman for the key exchange, and the `DHE` is ephemeral Diffie–Hellman).

Diffie-Hellman is slightly harder to break in theory than RSA, but not so much that it will be a deciding factor. `DHE` offers [perfect forward secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy) and because the key is *ephemeral* (i.e., never stored on disk), stealing the private key is much more difficult. Those two **are** deciding factors, so `DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA` should win for security.

The question [1024-bit DHE vs 2048-bit RSA](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/42816/15106) has a better comparison of the virtues of the two key exchanges, and the question [Is there any particular reason to use Diffie-Hellman over RSA for key exchange?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35521/15106) has a *very* detailed comparson between the two.

Comment: thank you for your answer and the clear explainations linked.